# Does a database of historic US Presidential election polling data exist?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, public-opinion

I want to do some research concerning the historic accuracy of presidential election polling. Is there anywhere I can find a database containing historic polling data from multiple pollsters? FiveThirtyEight makes available a spreadsheet of the polls they have tracked for 2016 and 2020. Is there anything similar to this for previous election cycles? Nate Silver (of FiveThirtyEight) mentions in his methodology for the 2016 model that "Our probabilities are based on the historical accuracy of election polls since 1972." I want to be able to look at that polling data if it exists somewhere.

Comment: Like the data here? [Historical polling for United States presidential elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_polling_for_United_States_presidential_elections).

Comment: @RickSmith, that data is useful, but only represents Gallup's polls. There is also no source provided for the data after 2008. I'm looking for polling from as many sources as possible all aggregated into a single database. If I can't find one pre-made, that wikipedia article will definitely help create it.

Comment: I expect what you are looking for will unfortunately be proprietary, not open source.
[CQ Press Voting and Elections Collection](https://library.cqpress.com/elections/) and [The Roper Center at Cornell University](https://ropercenter.cornell.edu/) both look promising but I don't have access to confirm.

Comment: @BrianZ, I have access to the Roper Center through my institution and it is quite useful for national-level data, though it is a bit cumbersome to work with. I was hoping to find something with state-level polling as well, which is something Roper Center does not typically track.